# startAt nor equalTo are working in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

What I want to do is paginate a set of items...
This is more or less the structure of what I have stored at firebase:

```
pics/ {
     "key_1": {
            "value":"00001"
            },
     "key_2": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_3": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_4": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_5": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_6": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_7": {
            "value":"00002"
            },
     "key_8": {
            "value":"00009"
            }
}
```

what I want to do is to paginate 5 items each page, if value equals to 00002, so

I do this for the first set:

```
firebase.database().ref('/pics').orderByChild('value').equalTo("00002").limitToFirst(5);
```

And this for the next ones:

```
firebase.database().ref('/pics').orderByChild('value').equalTo("00002", LAST_KEY).limitToFirst(5);
```

But it only works if I don't add the LAST_KEY parameter...  but, if I put a string with the last key (for instance "key_6") it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it worked when I did it this way...

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/pics').orderByChild('value').startAt("00002", (LAST_KEY? LAST_KEY : undefined)).limitToFirst(5);
```

Before this I was doing it this other way:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/pics').orderByChild('value');
if(LAST_KEY) usersRef = usersRef.startAt("00002", LAST_KEY);
if(!LAST_KEY) usersRef = usersRef.startAt("00002");
usersRef = usersRef.limitToFirst(5);
```

Now it works (and I like it more).